# Apply different textures to six faces of a cube, but something is wrong

Tags: opengl, graphics

Now I am applying six different textures to six faxes of a cube in OpenGL, but the result does not look like right. I load six bmp pictures from  my disk, and their size are all 256* 256.And I have used SOIL(Simple OpenGL Image Library: it can be downloaded here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lesson_06_texturing_update/47002/)to load bmp pictures to build textures.

Now I list my code here:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "SOIL.h"

GLuint texture[6];//6 textures for 6 faces of the cube

GLfloat xRot,yRot,zRot;//control cube's rotation

//load the bitmap and convert it into a texture
int LoadGLTextures()
{
int Status = 0;
char *bmpFile[6] =          {"BmpFile/Ferrary.bmp","BmpFile/Honda.bmp","BmpFile/Hust.bmp",
    "BmpFile/Lamborghini.bmp","BmpFile/NeHe.bmp","BmpFile/Porsche.bmp"};
for (int i = 0;i < 6;++i)
{
    texture[i] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
        bmpFile[i],
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
    printf("texture[%d]: %d\n",i,texture[i]);
    if(texture[i] == 0)
        Status = 0;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[i]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
}

return Status;
}

int init()
{
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
if(!LoadGLTextures())
    return 0;
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
return 1;
}

void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
glRotatef(xRot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glRotatef(yRot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glRotatef(zRot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

//glRotatef(45,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
//glRotatef(45,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]);

glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Front Face 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Back Face 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[2]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Top Face 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[3]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Bottom Face 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[4]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Right face 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[5]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
// Left Face 
// Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
// Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Top Right Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
// Top Left Of The Texture and Quad 
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
glEnd(); 

/*xRot += 0.3f;
yRot += 0.4f;
zRot += 0.5f;*/

glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w,int h)
{
if (0 == h)
    h = 1;

glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h,1,100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
switch(key){
    case 'x':
        xRot += 1.0f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'y':
        yRot += 1.0f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'z':
        zRot += 1.0f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutCreateWindow("Texture Map");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

This is the result after running:

http://hi.csdn.net/attachment/201203/11/2712336_1331434358OPyZ.jpg

The right result should be:

http://hi.csdn.net/attachment/201203/11/2712336_1331434425901v.jpg

Could someone tell me why?Is something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have several bugs.  The first bug is that you misspelled Ferrari when you typed in `"Ferrary.bmp"` and that's why your cube is missing one face.  Your second bug is that `LoadGLTextures` always returns `0`.  I think you meant to initialize `Status` to `1`, not `0`.

So both because of the fact that `Status` is initialized correctly AND you load the wrong BMP, your `LoadGLTextures` function fails and returns `0`.  This causes your `init` function to quit after calling `LoadGLTextures` before it even gets to `glShadeModel`.  Since it skips all the rest of the initialization functions you get incorrect perspective, too.  This leads to your third bug, which is that you never examined the return value of `init` and thus missed the fact that it was failing.

Moral of the story: Always check every single return value and print diagnostic error messages.

Comment: Thanks so much.My fault is that I wrongly initialize the variable Status to 0.I am so careless~~~